# link database and stmt and prepare

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a mysql php code 
if I put the ID and passwd it will check with database 
and link to the login success or login fail. 
but my code it failed to go to the login success even though id and passwd is correct

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'project');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//to check whether the username exists or not
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

$stmt->prepare("select pid, password from person where pid = '$username' and passwd = '$password'");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, MD5($password));
$stmt->bind_result($result,$result2);
$stmt->execute();
```

1. Im not sure my prepare statement and the bind_param is in the right position.
   it should compare the MD5(password) (encrypted) password with input password

**

```
if  ($stmt->fetch())
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['pid'] = $username;//login id
    header('Location: Login Successfully.php');
    exit();
}else{
$_SESSION['pid'] = $username;
header('Location: Failed to login.php');
}
```

**
and this is my  fetch. but it always go to the failed to login.php

this is my login.php before execute above code. it get the input id and passwd and pass it to the fetch code.

Login:
    Enter your username and password below:

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />

Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: `$stmt->prepare("select pid, password from person where pid = ? and passwd = ?");` instead of `$stmt->prepare("select pid, password from person where pid = '$username' and passwd = '$password'");`

Comment: it does not fix the problem...

Comment: oh it does i should change a few parameter .. thank you Sean

Comment: @Sean please leave the comment as an answer, so that kimchi can mark it as such. That way it won't show up as an unanswered question anymore

Answer (score 0):

When using `prepare()`, you need to use placeholders `?` instead of the actual variables. Also it looks like `passwd` should be `password`. So you will want to change

```
$stmt->prepare("select pid, password from person where pid = '$username' and passwd = '$password'");
```

to

```
$stmt->prepare("select pid, password from person where pid = ? and password = ?");
```